# Whois de dominios php api em json?

Tags: php, json, domínio

estou precisando fazer consultas de domínios, obter as informações sobre ele, dns, ip, responsável, etc. Consigo fazer para registro.br usando a api do nicBr https://rdap.registro.br/domain/ porém preciso para dominios .org, .net, .com, etc.
Vi a documentação do rdap = https://www.apnic.net/apnic-info/whois_search/about/rdap li essa referencia tbm mas não entendi: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7485

Alguém conhece um webservice/api que faça isso free?

Comment: Tentei usar outros sites genéricos que fazem whois mas tanto usando cUrl quanto file_get_contents é bloqueado..

Answer (score 1):

Descobri este site: http://jsonwhoisapi.com/

Faz o que você precisa e é bem fácil de usar. Abaixo código PHP pronto para você testar:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://jsonwhoisapi.com/api/v1/whois?identifier=google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_token); // trocar por sua ID:key
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if( curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200 )
{
    // em caso de erro na request
    die("Erro ao puxar jsonwhoisapi - HTTP_CODE: (". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) .")". print_r($response, true), 0);
}
curl_close($ch);

$dados = json_decode($response);

print_r($dados);
```